# Generic "An Error Has Occurred" When Editing SSRS Subscription - No Parameters Appearing

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I'm relatively new to SSRS Reporting. I'm attempting to manage a data-driven subscription for a two-part report on a SQL Server 2016 Developer instance that is acting as a dedicated SSRS server. At one time I was able to edit/manage a data-driven subscription for one report, but this no longer appears to be working and I'm getting a generic error.

**Steps to Reproduce Error:**

- Browse to SSRS instance at http://testReportServer/Reports/browse
- Click on the *Department* Folder
- Click on the *Report* Folder
- The *Report* folder contains a report sub-part (called Eval_rpt) and the main
  report (Evaluation_rpt)
- I click on the ellipses for Evaluation_rpt and click Manage because that's where the subscription is set up.
- I click on Subscriptions, and there is one there called **Test**
- I click on **Edit** next to the **Test** subscription
- The Edit Subscription page begins to load, then I'm presented with the generic "An error has occurred.
  Something went wrong. Please try again later."
- Enabled verbose logging on the SSRS instance and walked through reproducing this error several
  times. There's nothing in the SSRS log output that is meaningful or
  useful.
- Opening up Chrome/Firefox developer console, on the Network
  tab, I see an error 500 for Model.GetParameters
- When I click through the error that SSRS gives me, there should be two Parameters listed
  at the bottom of the Edit Subscription page, and they are not
  appearing for obvious reasons.

**Facts, Analysis, & Troubleshooting Steps so Far:**

- This ReportServer / ReportServerTempDB database used to reside on a
  SQL Server 2008 instance and were migrated to this 2016 instance late
  last year. This report has been working fine since that migration. It
  was only recently I tried updating this subscription and ran into
  this issue.
- This instance uses domain service accounts to run services (SQL Server, Reporting Service.) I've reviewed permissions/roles on those
  service accounts on both the SSRS server and the SQL Server hosting
  the remote data source for the report and sub-part, and they appear to be permissioned correctly.
- The report in question has data sources on a remote SQL Server (e.g. ProdServer.Domain.org) and the credentials configured in those data sources have rights to connect to and query the target database on ProdServer
- The owner of this report is the same service account used by the Reporting Services Service.
- I am attempting to edit this subscription with a Windows/AD account that has local administrative rights on the windows server, sa rights on the SQL Server Instance, and is a full administrator on the Reporting Server instance.
- This doesn't appear to be a double-hop issue as I've verified there's a trust relationship between these two servers, and I can see KERBEROS connection/authentication methods when I look for them
- The rsreportserver file is set up to use an authentication type of RsWindowsNegotiate
- I've reviewed/checked for shared/embedded data sources in the report parts. Where necessary, I've reconfig'd these reports to not use a shared data source to pull parameters, but instead redirected parameters to use a data source manually set up on the report parts themselves (manage
  the report part > data sources >  connect to a custom data source >
  provide AD credentials > test connection)
- I've confirmed that the service accounts in use have rights to not just the report server database but the rsExecRole and related subcomponents/stored procedures/tables within master and msdb.

Thanks in advance for any advice/suggestions you can offer.

Comment: We get the same error after upgrading to the latest version of Power BI report server.
Have you found the issue? And what did you do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to hear you're encountering this bug. We never did narrow down root cause on this. Sad to say, the report owner ended up rebuilding & redeploying the report parts & subparts from scratch. The SQL code behind the report parts was good, but there was a bug in the repor/subreport part metadata that we could never suss out.

Comment: Any update on this? We are experiencing the same issue...